Парсинг времени постов Telegram Telethon
Собственно в чём дилемма, имеется готовый код, который с файла жрёт данные формата @channel_name, пользователь вводит требуемую дату, программа считывает время постов в канале за эту дату, выводит в эксель табличку. Но дело в том, что это работает только с открытыми каналами. Не могу понять, как правильно реализовать это с закрытым каналом. пробовал и через invite link, валится ошибка что мол пользователь уже подписан на канал, и через -id, всё равно не получается.
